# Syntax match only within a particular region (but also within other nested ones)

Tags: syntax-highlighting

Is it possible to get VIM to recognize syntax changes inside a particular region? Specifically, I am trying to get LaTeX3's `\ExplSyntaxOn`...`\ExplSyntaxOff` syntax to be highlighted, but `only` inside a particular region. The `\makeatletter`...`\makeatother` syntax region would be similar.

Here is an example file to highlight:

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_@@_local_var_tl
\tl_new:N \g_@@_global_var_tl
\tl_if_eq:nnTF {\l_@@_local_var_tl} {\g_@@_global_var_tl}
{ Hello, world! }
{ Goodbye, world! }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N \l_@@_local_var_tl
\tl_new:N \g_@@_global_var_tl
\tl_if_eq:nnTF {\l_@@_local_var_tl} {\g_@@_global_var_tl}
{ Hello, world! }
{ Goodbye, world! }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I tried this so far (in ~/.vim/after/syntax/tex.vim):

```
syntax region texLaTeX3Zone matchgroup=texStatement start="\\ExplSyntaxOn\>"
  \   end="\\ExplSyntaxOff\>" skip="[^\\]%.*\\ExplSyntaxOff" transparent
  \ keepend

syntax match texLaTeX3DefCmd "\\[a-zA-Z_:@]\+" nextgroup=texDefParms,texCmdBody
  \   skipwhite skipnl contained containedin=texLaTeX3Zone
highlight link texLaTeX3DefCmd texStatement
```

However, anything that is inside braces (which is region `texCmdBody`) or after `\begin{document}` (which is region `texDocZone`), or any other region for that matter, doesn't get highlighted properly.

It doesn't work to leave `contained` off, as that would make it match everywhere, even outside the region, and it doesn't work to use `containedin=ALL`, because then it highlights it in other regions that are not contained within texLaTeX3Zone.

Short of making the new highlighting part of every region in the document---I only want it between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`---is there a way to do this?